# What should I read, Where should I start, and in What sequence - when reading Hindu religious books?

Tags: vedas, puranas, bhagavad-gita, upanishads, book-recommendation

I am a beginner of reading Hindu religious book. I have basic knowledge of Hindu religion, thought I also know that this religion is very vast and I want to expand my knowledge on this subject.

**Can you please let me know the list of books I should read and in what sequence? Also can you suggest me source as well (translated in Hindi or English)?**

I plan on starting with Gita (my mother has translated it to me when I was kid but I want to start from basics again). Then I was planning on reading the four Vedas (I don't have them yet but I am searching for them. I am not sure if I can find them online). After this I was planning on reading Purans and then Upanishads. **What is your recommendation? Am I going correct? Or Should I start with something else?
Are there any other books which I am not aware of and I should read?**

*Note for reviewer: Positive or constructive comments are welcome. If the question is incorrect then please tell me exactly what's wrong with it so I can correct it. or give me link for rules. This is a very basic questions for beginners. I am not a genius, but you can help me becoming one.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read whatever the religious book, of any religions, keep your mind open and argue if don't understand, don't accept everything on the name of AASTHA, try to find your GOD than different idols only.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thank you. The link you shared is exactly what I was looking.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Thank you, Your's link was very informative as well. And I wanted all that information.

Comment: @AliAdravi Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely keep it in mind. Very True.

Comment: @AliAdravi - Your comment is irrelevant. The question is specifically about Hindu religious books.